# Posting A Tweet With Codebird PHP 220/403

Tags: php, twitter

I am getting the following error when attempting to tweet something from my application:  object(stdClass)#6 (2) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#7 (2) { ["code"]=> int(220) ["message"]=> string(54) "Your credentials do not allow access to this resource." } } ["httpstatus"]=> int(403) }

I followed a tutorial on youtube and it seemed to work fine until I attempted to change it to post tweets.  Can someone check out my code and see what i'm doing wrong here?  Thanks

```
class TwitterAuth
{

protected $db;

protected $client;

protected $clientCallback = 'http://www.twittest.intelwalk.com/callback.php';

public function __construct(DB $db, \Codebird\Codebird $client)
{
    $this->db=$db;
    $this->client=$client;
}

public function getAuthUrl()
{
    $this->requestTokens();
    $this->verifyTokens();

    return $this->client->oauth_authenticate();
}

public function signedIn()
{

    return isset($_SESSION['user_id']);
}

public function signIn()
{
    if($this->hasCallback())
    {
        $this->verifyTokens();

        $reply = $this->client->oauth_accessToken([
            'oauth_verifier' => $_GET['oauth_verifier']
            ]);

        if($reply->httpstatus === 200)
        {

            $this->storeTokens($reply->oauth_token, $reply->oauth_token_secret);

            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $reply->user_id;

            $this->storeUser($reply);

            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

public function signOut()
{
    unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
}

protected function hasCallback()
{
    return isset($_GET['oauth_verifier']);
}

protected function requestTokens()
{
    $reply = $this->client->oauth_requestToken([

        'oauth_callback' => $this->clientCallback

        ]);
    $this->storeTokens($reply->oauth_token,$reply->oauth_token_secret);
}

protected function storeTokens($token,$tokenSecret)
{
    $_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $token;
    $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $tokenSecret;
}

protected function verifyTokens()
{
    $this->client->setToken($_SESSION['oauth_token'],$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);

}

protected function storeUser($payload)
{
    $this->db->query("

        INSERT INTO users (twitter_id, twitter_username)
        VALUES ({$payload->user_id},'{$payload->screen_name}')
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = id
        ");

}

public function tweet($message)
{
    $reply =  $this->client->statuses_update(['status' => $message]);

    var_dump($reply);
```

Here is my index:

```
require_once 'app/init.php';

$auth = new TwitterAuth($db,$client);





?>

<?php if($auth->signedIn()): ?>
    <p>You are signed in. <a href="signout.php">Sign out</a></p>

<?php echo 'Test';
$auth->tweet('Hello World');
echo 'Test'; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <p><a href="<?php echo $auth->getAuthUrl(); ?>">Sign in with Twitter</a></p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Any ideas would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you are setting the consumer key/secret pair and getting the Codebird instance:

```
Codebird::setConsumerKey($this->consumer_key, $this->consumer_secret);
$this->twitter = Codebird::getInstance();
```

Maybe that was removed for posting here, but as I understand it you need to authenticate your app or you won't have permission to post, regardless of knowing your Twitter username and password.

Also, in the app configuration on Twitter's dev site you need "read and write" permissions.